# add try catch around highlighted code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm refactoring some code and there are tons of functions with no try catch statements that are causing problems.

Is there a keyboard shortcut in VS 2010 to allow me to select an entire function or highlighted code and add a try catch end try statement around it...with the highlighted code automatically ending up under try ?

Just looking for a shortcut

Comment: As a heads up, you're probably going to get comments about fixing the code so it doesn't/can't create exceptions (since the exceptions are that common).  Is there a reason the code can't be improved?

Comment: 2023: they added this functionality, [but only to JS/TS](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_surround-with-snippets-for-jsts)... Let's hope they add this also for other languages like python soon!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not aware of a keyboard short-cut, but there's a right-click available.

- Highlight the code for your try block.
- Right click and select
- "Surround with..." Scroll down the selection until you see the "try"
  snippet label.
- There you go!

Hope this helps!

I'll dig around to see if there's a keyboard short cut for this.  There probably is -- there's hundreds of them.

**UPDATE**: Looks like the [keyboard shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: interesting, i'll mark this as the answer but on my installation there is no "Surround with" option and CTRL K, CTRL S says "not currently available" - i've tried it in several projects

Answer (score 5):

Download this free addon and then right click and surround with !

(Don't forget to give it 1+ )

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yatki.vscode-surround

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 Update

they added this functionality, **[but only for JS/TS](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_surround-with-snippets-for-jsts)**... Let's hope they add this also for other languages like python soon!

Answer (score -1):

It's not built in, but it is easy enough to roll your own.
Look into using the built in macro facility.