# Is there a fast way to embed a piece of source into a try-catch clause, using the Visual Studio editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on a C# application, where something seems to be going wrong. In order to know what's going wrong, I would like to replace the following code by the same code, embedded in a try-catch clause, so replace:

```
Do_Something();
```

By:

```
try
{
    Do_Something();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error($"[{message.GetType().Name}]:" + ex);
}
```

At the moment, I'm typing the `try {` myself and using copy/paste for the `catch(...){}`-clause, but I wondering if there would be some feature in Visual Studio, making this easier (e.g. I select the `Do_Something()`, press some shortcut and the whole thing gets done).

This question was marked as a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930548), but my question goes a bit deeper: the mentioned snippets seem to be hardcoded (the `try`-snippet contains a simple `throw` instead of the `_log.Error()`-instruction). Is there a way to configure the existing snippets or to create new ones?

Comment: You can add your own "snippets", see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2022  and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2022

Comment: FWIW The catch block you show here is losing a lot of detail like stack trace etc. You are also relying on the `ToString` override to give you the exception message instead of explicitly using `ex.Message`.

Comment: @DavidG: thanks for your advise, but the true value in my `catch`-block lies in the `message.GetType().Name`: it's a client-server application, who is constantly sending messages back and forth between client and server, hence knowledge of that message is enough to find the issue, if any.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add your custom snippet, Just like what @Matthew Watson pointed out in the comments.

`custom.snippet` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Try Catch Block with Logging</Title>
      <Shortcut>trycatch</Shortcut>
      <Description>Adds a try-catch block with logging.</Description>
      <Author>Your Name</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>logError</ID>
          <ToolTip>The method used to log errors.</ToolTip>
          <Default>_log.Error</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>messageType</ID>
          <ToolTip>The type of the message.</ToolTip>
          <Default>message.GetType().Name</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[try
{
    $selected$
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    $logError$("["+$messageType$+"]: " + ex);
}]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

[Import a code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2022#import-a-code-snippet)

> - You can import a snippet to your Visual Studio installation by using the Code Snippets Manager. Open it by selecting Tools > Code Snippets
>   Manager.
> - Select the Import button.
> - Go to the location where you saved the code snippet in the previous procedure, select it, and select Open.
> - The Import Code Snippet dialog opens, asking you to choose where to add the snippet from the choices in the right pane. One of the choices
>   should be My Code Snippets. Select it, select Finish, and then select
>   OK.
> - The snippet is copied to one of the following locations, depending on the code language and the version of Visual Studio that you're
>   using:
>
> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My
> Code Snippets %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Code
> Snippets\Visual Basic\My Code Snippets
>
> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My
> Code Snippets %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Code
> Snippets\Visual Basic\My Code Snippets

- Restart your Vs 2022 after importing.
- Highlight the code where you want to insert snippet and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>
- Select the folder where you saved the snippet and select the snippet,
  with this example you will see the `title` of the snippet i.e "Try Catch Block with Logging".